# Apache can't load mod-php5.so

Tags: php, apache

I've suddenly started having a problem with Apache2 and PHP after a recent update. Apache won't start, giving me the following error:

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 227 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Cannot load mods-enabled/mod-php5.so into server: /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mod-php5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've followed advice on a couple sites, leading me to do the following things:

In apache2.conf:
Changed /etc/apache2/modules to /etc/apache2/mods-enabled
Changing mod-php5.so to mod-php55.sp

Reinstall libapache2-mod-php5
ldconfig
whereis mod-php5.so (no results, also tried mod-php55.so and mod-php.so)

WHere is mod-php*.so located, and why is Apache suddenly not finding it?

EDIT: Sorry, forgot to say I'm running Linux Mint 17 x64.

Comment: First of all ... *throw away* your "advice," wherever it came from, and start zeroing-in on the **actual problem** as seen by **the software that is presently having it.** *(Apache ...)* "Wive's Tales" are nothing but a waste of time. The bottom line is that Apache failed to load the module. (Therefore, the "syntax error" is a *side effect* which has no actual bearing upon the **root** cause of the problem.)

Comment: By far the most likely root-cause in this case is that *"you updated to a version of (Ubuntu) that **removed(!!) PHP5 altogether(!!)** because The Implementors decided that "PHP5 was evil, and from now on it's PHP7." ... Welcome to My Nightmare ..."

Comment: I checked my PHP version (php --version), and it hasn't been upgraded to 7 yet. PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.19 (cli) (built: Jul 28 2016 19:31:33)